# Data from react-hook-form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hook-form

does anyone know how to get the React-hook-form data without the name? For example:

Currently the data comes like this:

`{"message": "Fred Fliston"}`

But, I just wanted to get the name:

`Fred Fliston`

Can someone help me?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Perhaps you can explain better how this is used, e.g. provide more code samples where this is called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I guess that you fetch the data from a file.

In this case, if the file name is data, for example:

```
console.log(data.message[0)
```